# How to load json 3d object and put it at origin in threejs

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

How can we load json object and place it at the origin. Neither object.position.x nor mesh.position.x helped me to object into origin. I want to get maximum and minimum x,y and z values of the object so that I can create a object bounding box. And when I draw that box on the screen centered at the origin it will contain whole object inside it. The way I'm doing it right now does not work if object's position is not at the origin.

Answer (score 0):

If the `mesh.geometry.boundingBox` attribute is not set use the `mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox()` method to set the attribute. Then (writing this explicitly, you can do it with Vector operations)

```
var geometryCenter = new THREE.Vector3();
geometryCenter.x = mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.x + ( mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.x - mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.x ) / 2;
geometryCenter.y = mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.y + ( mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.y - mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.y ) / 2;
geometryCenter.z = mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.z + ( mesh.geometry.boundingBox.max.z - mesh.geometry.boundingBox.min.z ) / 2;

mesh.position.set( -geometryCenter.x, -geometryCenter.y, -geometryCenter.z );
```

Should place your mesh at the origin.

Comment: mesh.geometry.computeBoundingBox(); gives undefined.

Comment: you need to link with the un-minified version of three.js and trace through the code to find out why. seems there is a problem with the object.

Answer (score 0):

Call mesh.geometry.center(), and it will offset the geometry itself to be centered around the origin.